# Creating a unique list with beautiful soup from href attribute Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, unique, href

I am trying to crate a unique list of all the hrefs on my anchor tags

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pprint

url = 'http://barrowslandscaping.com/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")
print soup

tag = soup.find_all('a', {"href": True})
set(tag)
for tags in tag:
    print tags.get('href')
```

result:

```
http://barrowslandscaping.com/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/services/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/design-consultation/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/hydroseeding-sodding/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/landscape-installation/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/full-service-maintenance/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/portfolio/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/about-us/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/contact/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/design-consultation/
http://barrowslandscaping.com/full-service-maintenance/
```

I have tried moving the set(tag) into the for loop but that didnt change my results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can't call `set()` in place, it's a conversion that returns a value.

```
tag_set = set(tags)
```

Second, `set` doesn't necessarily understand the difference between Tag objects in BeautifulSoup. As far as it's concerned, two separate tags were found in the HTML so they're not unique and should both remain in the set. It has no idea that they have the same href value.

Instead, you should first extract the href attributes into a list and convert those to a set instead.

```
tags = soup.find_all('a', {"href": True})
# extract the href values to a new array using a list comprehension
hrefs = [tag.get('href') for tag in tags]
href_set = set(hrefs)

for href in href_set:
    print href
```

This can be further simplified using a set comprehension:

```
tags = soup.find_all('a', {"href": True})
href_set = {tag.get('href') for tag in tags}

for href in href_set:
    print href
```

Comment: @BatsAuto if this solves your problem, mark it correct. Otherwise let me know in these comments if there's something else you're trying to do.

Comment: why not just `href_set = {tag.get('href') for tag in tags}`?

Comment: I'm trying to illustrate the use of `set()` to convert lists, which the OP was trying to do. I could add the set comprehension in to the answer though.

Comment: Sure but they may as well learn to do it in one step, judging by their failure to assign the result of a set call, I imagine they may not have know you could just do it in a single step.

Comment: I agree that it's good to know, but better they understand the fundamentals first, before worrying about an optimization.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer.